# Standard deviation and long-tail data

Tags: standard-deviation, kurtosis

Sorry, I don't know the math words.

I have a data set that looks like the following. I am counting things, and the graph shows how many of each thing there is. for example, I have a LOT of thing #0, and not many of thing #300.

In my application, things that are ubiquitous are assumed to exist; I don't need to include them in my reports - they are just noise. In a real world example, if you listed all the things in the room in which you sit, most would list tables, chairs, computers, etc. Only the most contrarian person would list bacteria and air.

My complete graph has a much longer tail than you see here - 10x more data. The average for my data set is very low, something like 30. The standard deviation is about 300.

Is it mathematically sensible for me to choose a number of standard deviations and remove the data that is "to the left" of the cut-off? In my case, say I choose 4 standard deviations. 30 + 4*300 = 1230. So I'd cut off everything with a count greater than 1230.

Am I using this right?

[image]

Comment: "Bacteria" and "air molecules" would *by far* be the most numerous, as well as the obvious answers to, say, a physicist or chemist.  This isn't to say you're incorrect, but only to point out that your question implicitly supposes some knowledge of what "things" are of interest.  That has no statistical or mathematical answer.  Ultimately, any solution to your problem would be tantamount to deciding which modifications to the data are of consequence and which are not.  Thus, to be answerable your question must provide some information about that.

Comment: @whuber what I am looking for is guidance on which techniques are suitable for a dataset that resembles the above.  Exactly _what_ us being counted is not important.

Comment: Unfortunately, either you have to be able to describe your problem in clear statistical and mathematical terms or you have to describe it in ways that enable us to figure out what the problem might be.  You're not accomplishing the first, so indeed, to understand the question it is *crucially* important to learn more about your application.  Otherwise we are left with a purely mathematical question that hasn't been formulated in an answerable way.

Comment: @whuber ok. I am counting words across several documents, and I want to know which words are so ubiquitous that I can ignore them. The mix of words change regularly as more documents are consumed so I can't just say, the 100 most used words should be ignored.

Comment: That likely comes down to *why* you are counting the words.

Comment: With all due respect, you're trolling me at this point.

Comment: Not at all.  Your phrase "I can ignore them" hints that you are doing this for some subsequent purpose.  Whether you can ignore data depends on that purpose, the procedures you will be applying, and the consequences of incorrectly ignoring the data.  This kind of consideration is *essential:* it's one of the things that distinguishes statistics from mathematics (on the one hand) and arbitrary magic (on the other hand).  So far, you haven't supplied sufficient hints about this crucial information.  I'll stop asking for them, because it appears you don't really want a good answer.

Comment: I want to ignore the ubiquitous words because they don't add information and they make my UI turn black with unhelpful lines, circles, and labels.

Comment: That might be a more than adequate criterion: remove the most frequent words until the point where you can use your UI.  People have used worse criteria than that to select and analyze data!  I am being serious, not flippant; but I can't help thinking there might be some more constructive approaches, such as to use a different UI altogether to accomplish whatever your goals might be.

Comment: Definitely. But it takes time to develop new code and my UI is 'sploding *now*. And as we ingest more and more documents, we always face the prospect of blowing up the UI.  So the idea here is to try to use a little science to make a best guess on where the cutoff should be.

Comment: In natural language processing (NLP), this type of task is typically done by removing [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_word) (short, common words such as 'a', 'the', 'in') as part of the text pre-processing. Would stop-word removal help solve your problem? See, for example, Chetna Khanna's article [Text pre-processing: Stop words removal using different libraries](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-pre-processing-stop-words-removal-using-different-libraries-f20bac19929a).

Comment: @Lynn it would help. We're already removing standard stop words.  We have some that are specific to our problem domain, evidently.

Comment: Another suggestion is [Term frequency-inverse document frequency (TF-IDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (if you're not already using it). TF-IDF is a statistic used in information retrieval/NLP that measures the importance of words in a collection of documents and it can be used to help identify domain-specific stop words. Would this help?

Comment: We're looking into it and will probably be spinning up a project within a month or two